# How to extract hex_num which means opcode+operand

Tags: dataframe, assembly, extract, disassembly, opcode

I am new to Capstone and PE structure... beg your indulgence

I want to extract hex number which means opcode and operands in Python using Capstone

Here is my example:

if there is a file that looks like this

.text:00404499 8B 0D 14 61 41 00
  mov     ecx, dword_416114

the hex num -'8D' is the hex number including (mov, ecx, dword_416114) right?

so I tried to extract the exact hex num, but i am having trouble...

Here is my code:

```
for ins in cs.disasm(pe.sections[0].get_data(), 0x0): 

    print("0x%x:\t%s\t%s" %(ins.address, ins.mnemonic, ins.op_str))
```

above code will show this:

0x0:    xor eax, 0xff77ee8b

0x5:    mov ch, dh

0x7:    ja  0xffffff9f

...
0x15:   inc esi

how can i get what i want?

Comment: Most instructions have a ModRM byte to encode the operands; for some (like `mov-immediate` to register, push/pop, and 32-bit mode inc/dec, and many immediate-with-EAX instructions), that uses the low 3 bits of the opcode, or (e.g. for `cdq`) is/are implicit.  Also, some instructions have a multi-byte mnemonic.  So the result you want is all the bytes *other than* immediate bytes, or displacement bytes in addressing modes?  (But AVX/AVX2 `vpblendvb` uses an `imm8` to encode the 4th operand.  I think that's unique; others only use REX, VEX, or EVEX + ModRM to encode up to 3 explicit operands.)

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. If you are using an existing disassembly library, you need to reference its documentation to access the information you need. If you don't understand what a specific field represents, edit the question to be self contained so people don't need to get used to third party libraries (especially if they are *python* libraries...). In your specific "example", are you sure you are disassembling the right section at the right offset? PE files have an entry-point. As Peter said, it's not clear what "hex_num" means.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I wanna get all the bytes other than immediate bytes !